# File formatting in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: html, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am executing certain operation using a script and writing the results to a file. Finally I should send the content of the file to specified users of the Jenkins Job.

Using the following the piece of code to get the output.

```
def result=readFile("output")
echo "${result}"
desired = result.split("\n")
notify("${desired}")
```

But this is not helping me for what I am expecting for. **The issue is that the content is showing as list of elements like below**:

```
persistentvolumeclaims is above threshold value with usage of 7 , secrets is above threshold value with usage of 12 , replicationcontrollers is above threshold value with usage of 29
```

But the **acutal content of the file is proper format**:

```
********************************************************************** 
                               opprovdemo 
 ********************************************************************** 
persistentvolumeclaims is above threshold value with usage of 7 
secrets is above threshold value with usage of 12 
replicationcontrollers is above threshold value with usage of 29
```

Even tried this code:

```
def result=readFile("output")
echo "${result}"
notify("${desired}")
```

But no use, it is **just showing as paragraph like this**:

```
********************************************************************** opprovdemo ********************************************************************** persistentvolumeclaims is above threshold value with usage of 7 secrets is above threshold value with usage of 12 replicationcontrollers is above threshold value with usage of 29
```

Adding *notify* function details:

```
def notify(status){
  emailext (
  to: "email-id",
  subject: "'${env.BUILD_TAG}!'",
  attachLog: true,
  body: """<style>
  body, table, td, th, p {
    font-family:verdana,helvetica,sans serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:black;
  }
  td.bg1 { color:white; background-color:#595959; font-size:120% }
  td.console { font-family:courier new, lucida console; }
  </style>
  <body>
  <table border=2 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=2 width="40%">
  <tr>
  <td align="left" width="30%">
  <img
  src="*****/headshot.png" />
  </td>
  <td valign="center" width="70%">
  <b style="font-size: 170%;">OSE RESOURCE USAGE INFORMATION</b>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>URL:</td>
  <td>
  <a href='${env.BUILD_URL}'>${env.JOB_NAME}</a>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>BUILD STATUS:</td>
  <td>${status}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>DATE/TIME:</td>
  <td>${env.BUILD_TIMESTAMP}</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
  </body>"""
  )
}
```

**What should be done in such a way that the content will show as the same way that of output file?**

Comment: Which environment is your Jenkins deployed? Linux or Windows?

Comment: I believe you are asking Jenkins nodes environment...Its Linux

Comment: How are you reading the file? Using cat? Most probably this is related to how you read it. Please post that code also